# Refreshing in-memory cache across multiple instances in Azure

Tags: azure, web-applications

I have an Azure web app which uses in-memory caching, adding keys as follows

```
    public static void Add(object item, string key)
    {
        var wrapper = new CacheItemWrapper()
        {
            InsertedAt = DateTime.Now,
            Item = item
        };
        MemoryCache.Default.Add(key, wrapper, ObjectCache.InfiniteAbsoluteExpiration);
    }
```

Occasionally the user of our application will make a change which requires the cache to refresh. I can call a method which clears the cache, the problem is, it only works on the instance which picks up the request. Other instances still have the old values in memory.

Is there any way I can do either of these things

a) run a method across multiple instances, or
b) raise an event which all instances listen for?

The code above could be changed to expire within a short time so that all instances could pick this up. However, it's quite a long process to update the cache and this might affect performance. Given the application knows when it needs to refresh the cache, it would be much better and more responsive if it could be done programmatically.

Comment: You could use a distributed cache like https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cache/

Comment: Used to use Redis but performance proved a problem. Plan B is to return to it.

Answer (score 0):

I know its more than half a decade old question. But still a use case which people might be struggling with.
Recently landed into similar requirement.

The solution proposed from someone in team (smarter than me) was to include a message broker like Redis/ServiceBus and let the app instances listen on it.

As soon as there is a new message on the broker, all the instances of App service will be notified and they can handle the notification with the implementation to clear entire cache or specific keys.